# Firebase and IoT devices

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, intel-edison

I'm running a node app on an IoT device (e.g. Edison). The server app should operate as if it's a client app. From the firebase web client SDK, it's possible to signin as a user. The node app should signin to firebase on behalf of the user that owns the device (i.e. registered the device) and thereby have the same restrictions that a user signing in from a browser would have. However, the firebase server SDK (for node.js) doesn't support the notion of signing in. And, I can't run the web client SDK on Node.